# Public class requires public members (when accessing members)?

Tags: java, class, public, members

I noticed in my Java book, in the section about packages and the private modifier, that the code redundantly used `private` on the class and the members of the class being accessed outside of the package.

```
package bookpack;

public class Book {
    private String title;
    private String author;
    private int pubDate;

    public Book(String t, String a, int d) {
        title = t;
        author = a;
        pubDate = d;
    }

    public void show() {
        System.out.println(title);
        System.out.println(author);
        System.out.println(pubDate + "\n"); 
    }
}
```

When I remove the `public` from `show()`, Eclipse gives an error stating that the member cannot be accessed (when attempting to do so from another package).  I understand that it is because it is not `public` and therefore cannot be accessed from outside the package. However, since the class is public, I thought that all members of the class would then be `public`, unless otherwise specified.  That would follow the "general specifications here, specific specifications later" style, similar to inheritance.  Much like how you cannot call a dynamic object from a static method.  So why is the `public` tag required on the member of a public class?  How does a `public` tag affect accessibility in the context of retrieving a public member of a class

Comment: Nope. Access modifiers only affect the thing they are directly modifying. A `public class` means a `public class` only, not a `public class` and `public members`. I suppose this is at least partially also linked to the fact that package-private visibility is the default visibility in Java. That more follows the "limit visibility" idea for object-oriented programming.

Comment: Check [Controlling Access to Members of a Class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html)

Comment: Welcome to Java. Your assumption[all members of the class would then be public, unless otherwise specified] is correct for C++ but not for java

Comment: The lack of a modifier is already in use to mean "package access", so it cannot be used to mean "same as class".

Comment: So does Java require the class be `public` if one or more of its members are `public`, or can you forgo that by only tagging the members you need `public`?

Comment: Nope. Access modifiers are considered separately from each other. You can have a package-private class with public members.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Expanded from the comments section

Access modifiers only apply to the things they directly modify. Thus, `public` on a class only affects the visibility of the class -- *not* the visibility of any of its members. Thus, you can provide `public` members for a package-private class, which could be useful if you have an abstract class you want to keep hidden from the public API.

In addition, the lack of a visibility modifier is already defined to mean package-private visibility. Thus, it cannot be used to mean "same as class". As for *why* the language is designed that way, the best I could come up with is that it might have seemed like a good balance between limiting visibility to the outside world while still allowing different top-level classes to interact.

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out in comment

> Access level modifiers determine whether other classes can use a
>   particular field or invoke a particular method. There are two levels
>   of access control:
>
> - At the top level—public, or package-private (no explicit modifier).
> - At the member level—public, private, protected, or package-private (no explicit modifier).
>
> A class may be declared with the modifier public, in which case that
>   class is visible to all classes everywhere. If a class has no modifier
>   (the default, also known as package-private), it is visible only
>   within its own package (packages are named groups of related classes —
>   you will learn about them in a later lesson.)
>
> At the member level, you can also use the public modifier or no
>   modifier (package-private) just as with top-level classes, and with
>   the same meaning. For members, there are two additional access
>   modifiers: private and protected. The private modifier specifies that
>   the member can only be accessed in its own class. The protected
>   modifier specifies that the member can only be accessed within its own
>   package (as with package-private) and, in addition, by a subclass of
>   its class in another package.

For further details kindly go through following [link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html)

Comment: I understand that, but the article mentions nothing of `public` in the context of both class and member.  My only question was regarding the relationship between a `private/public` class and a `private/public` member of said class.  However, user: user3580294 explained it thoroughly.